# What's the difference between "Mediary" and "Intermediary"?

Tags: meaning, differences

I can't find a definition for Mediary, I thought they kind of mean the same thing. But how they each precisely defined? And can someone use a good example of both? Thanks

Comment: Here is a similar case: `representative` v.s. `presentative`. Many derivatives or variants with prefixes/suffixes grow more popular over a "root-form" of a word mostly because of relevance on a daily basis.

Comment: @Crosscounter http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/presentative Whereas, cf. MJ Robson in my answer for *mediary.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has got to be a "word" though used in specific domains, in very formal writing. In all citations below, emphasis has been added on purpose.

Paul Cobley, Ed., Routledge companion to semiotics and linguistics, 1963, [p.33](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=YSKCAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA33&q=mediary#v=one%20page&q=mediary&f=false)

> Thirdness can be tentatively qualified as that which brings about mediation between two other happenings in such a manner that they interrelate with each other in the same way they interrelate with the third happening as a result of its **mediary** role. … Due to the **mediary** role of thirdness, each of the categories can intermittently play the role of any of the other categories.

Appears like the word is used in a similar sense to *intermediary* with a subtle difference. esp., in academic writing, in the fields of computer science (*information mediary*), biology (*bio-mediary*), law, commerce (*service mediary*) and philosophy. A large number of such instances can be found online ([Books](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22mediary%22%20-intermediary%20), ~15k; [Web](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22mediary%22%20-intermediary) ~117k).

[Abrahamson JA](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18974809), et al., on pubmed:

> Lay information **mediaries** (LIMs) seek information on behalf or because of others, without necessarily being asked to do so or engaging in follow up, and have represented more than 50% of health information seekers in prior studies.

[MJ Robson](http://mjrobson.com/wp/what-is-a-mediary/) explains:

> What is a Mediary?
> … The word Mediary has no dictionary definition, nor does it have any common usages. Inter-Mediary has a definition. Like other compound words, such as Inter-National, Inter-Denominational, or Inter-Species, it seemed to me that the second half of Inter-Mediary should stand as a word in its own right.
> Well, it doesn’t.
> It HAS been used by others, mostly in the digital information world, usually referring to a ‘portal, or aggregation’ model like Travelocity.com. **A middle man, with or without a distinction. So, some very smart people have tried to use Mediary as an adjective or and adverb, but never as a Noun.**

COCA has at least two entries for the word:

- [Kent Nelson](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/x4.asp?t=4121677&ID=666303827), *Who Is Danny Pendergast?* 2011
- [Geoff Ryman](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/x4.asp?t=4076019&ID=519123518) in 'Fantasy & Science Fiction,' **117** 3/4; p.105, 2009

Answer (score -2):

There is no English word "mediary", as the word "intermediary" is a borrowing from the French. The closest word in English to "mediary" is "mediator", and both Mediator and intermediary have nearly identical meanings, a third person who acts in negotiations between two other parties.

Comment: Hmmm well I got the word in Thesaurus.com when I searched "Proxy"

Comment: There is a legal definition only for mediary, which is what you'd expect.